# Mounting a remote drive and setting user-id

Tags: 10.04, mount

I'm about to do a fresh install of 10.10 Desktop on my work PC.

I previously had 10.04 and I had the `/home` of our main server mounted to `/mnt/home`.  I remember back then I had to change my local user id to match that used on the id of my user on the remote server, so I will have the correct permissions to all my files.

My question is whether I can set this id during the setup or must I do it post installation (effectively changing the automatically assigned id).

Also, is that the best practice to work on a mounted location or is there anything more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html) can be used with the *Alternate CD* to [specify several parameters of the initial user](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-contents.html#preseed-account), including the UID; this *might* work with the regular *Desktop CD* as well (GUI installer).

Concerning the ID matching between client and server, this really depends on the protocol  that is being used to share the files over the network: NFS usually requires matching UID on the client and server; SMB/CIFS does not (but it requires an additional "login" step when you mount the remote filesystem).  NFS is traditionally used in UNIX environments, while SMB/CIFS is the (only) network filesystem available on Windows hosts (by default).